# Can't get ids assigned to an attribute in OpenGL

Tags: c++, c, opengl, glsl, shader

I am trying to have OpenGL automatically assign an ID to a glsl-attribute, but it is failing.

My main program:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/glfw3.h>

#include "test.h"
#include "shader_utils.h"

static void error_callback(int error, const char* description) {
    std::cout << description << std::endl;
}

static void key_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int a, int b) {
    if (a == GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE && b == GLFW_PRESS) {
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, GL_TRUE);
    }
}

void test()
{
    std::cout << "Starting up" << std::endl;
    init();
    run();
}

GLFWwindow *window;
GLuint shaders;
GLuint vertexBuffer;

int init() {
    glfwSetErrorCallback(error_callback);

    if(!glfwInit()) {
        return -1;
    }

    window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "GLFW test", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window)  {
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    glfwSetKeyCallback(window, key_callback);

    glewExperimental = true;
    glewInit();

    shaders = LoadShaders("vertex.glsl", "fragment.glsl");

    GLuint vao_id;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao_id);
    glBindVertexArray(vao_id);


    static const GLfloat vertex_data[] = {
        // Bottom
        -.5f, -.5f, -.5f,   1.f, 0.f, 0.f,
        -.5f, -.5f,  .5f,   1.f, 0.f, 0.f,
         .5f, -.5f,  .5f,   1.f, 0.f, 0.f,
    };

    glGenBuffers(1, &vertexBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertex_data), vertex_data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
}

void checkE() {
    std::cout << "Checking for errors: ";
    int err;
    int a = 0;
    while((err = glGetError()) != GL_NO_ERROR) {
        std::cout << "Error: " << err << std::endl;
        a = 1;
    }

    if(a == 0) {
        std::cout << "no errors" << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout.flush();
}

int run() {
    GLfloat angle = 0;

    while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        glUseProgram(shaders);

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);

        GLuint attrLocation = glGetAttribLocation(shaders, "location");
        GLuint attrColor = glGetAttribLocation(shaders, "color");

        std::cout << "AttribLocation('location'): ";
        std::cout << glGetAttribLocation(shaders, "location") << std::endl;
        std::cout << "AttribLocation('color'): ";
        std::cout << glGetAttribLocation(shaders, "color") << std::endl;

        checkE();
        std::cout << std::endl;

        std::cout << "glEnableVertexAttribArray()" << std::endl;
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(attrLocation);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(attrColor);

        checkE();
        std::cout << std::endl;

        std::cout << "glVertexAttribPointer();" << std::endl;

        glVertexAttribPointer(
                        glGetAttribLocation(shaders, "location"), // Attribute
                        3, // Size
                        GL_FLOAT, // Size
                        GL_FALSE, // Normalized
                        24, // Stride
                        (GLvoid*) 0 // Offset
                    );

        checkE();
        std::cout << std::endl;


        std::cout << "glVertexAttribPointer();" << std::endl;
        glVertexAttribPointer(
                        glGetAttribLocation(shaders, "color"),
                        3,
                        GL_FLOAT,
                        GL_FALSE,
                        24,
                        (GLvoid*) (3*sizeof(GLfloat))
                    );
        checkE();
        std::cout << std::endl;

        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

        checkE();
        std::cout << std::endl;

        glDisableVertexAttribArray(attrLocation);
        glDisableVertexAttribArray(attrColor);

        checkE();
        std::cout << std::endl;

        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();

        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, GL_TRUE);
    }

    glfwDestroyWindow(window);
    glfwTerminate();
}
```

Output from program:

```
Starting up
Compiling shader : vertex.glsl

Compiling shader : fragment.glsl

Linking program

AttribLocation('location'): -1
AttribLocation('color'): -1
Checking for errors: no errors

glEnableVertexAttribArray()
Checking for errors: Error: 1281

glVertexAttribPointer();
Checking for errors: Error: 1281

glVertexAttribPointer();
Checking for errors: Error: 1281

Checking for errors: no errors

Checking for errors: Error: 1281
```

Shader loader:

```
#include "shader_utils.h"

#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

#include "GL/glew.h"
#include "GL/glfw3.h"


GLuint LoadShaders(const char * vertex_file_path, const char * fragment_file_path){

    // Create the shaders
    GLuint VertexShaderID = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    GLuint FragmentShaderID = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

    // Read the Vertex Shader code from the file
    std::string VertexShaderCode;
    std::ifstream VertexShaderStream(vertex_file_path, std::ios::in);
    if(VertexShaderStream.is_open())
    {
        std::string Line = "";
        while(getline(VertexShaderStream, Line))
            VertexShaderCode += "\n" + Line;
        VertexShaderStream.close();
    } else {
        std::cout << "could not open\n";
    }

    // Read the Fragment Shader code from the file
    std::string FragmentShaderCode;
    std::ifstream FragmentShaderStream(fragment_file_path, std::ios::in);
    if(FragmentShaderStream.is_open()){
        std::string Line = "";
        while(getline(FragmentShaderStream, Line))
            FragmentShaderCode += "\n" + Line;
        FragmentShaderStream.close();
    }

    GLint Result = GL_FALSE;
    int InfoLogLength;

    // Compile Vertex Shader
    printf("Compiling shader : %s\n", vertex_file_path);
    char const * VertexSourcePointer = VertexShaderCode.c_str();
    glShaderSource(VertexShaderID, 1, &VertexSourcePointer , NULL);
    glCompileShader(VertexShaderID);

    // Check Vertex Shader
    glGetShaderiv(VertexShaderID, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &Result);
    glGetShaderiv(VertexShaderID, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &InfoLogLength);
    std::vector<char> VertexShaderErrorMessage(InfoLogLength);
    glGetShaderInfoLog(VertexShaderID, InfoLogLength, NULL, &VertexShaderErrorMessage[0]);
    fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", &VertexShaderErrorMessage[0]);

    // Compile Fragment Shader
    printf("Compiling shader : %s\n", fragment_file_path);
    char const * FragmentSourcePointer = FragmentShaderCode.c_str();
    glShaderSource(FragmentShaderID, 1, &FragmentSourcePointer , NULL);
    glCompileShader(FragmentShaderID);

    // Check Fragment Shader
    glGetShaderiv(FragmentShaderID, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &Result);
    glGetShaderiv(FragmentShaderID, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &InfoLogLength);
    std::vector<char> FragmentShaderErrorMessage(InfoLogLength);
    glGetShaderInfoLog(FragmentShaderID, InfoLogLength, NULL, &FragmentShaderErrorMessage[0]);
    fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", &FragmentShaderErrorMessage[0]);

    // Link the program
    fprintf(stdout, "Linking program\n");
    GLuint ProgramID = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(ProgramID, VertexShaderID);
    glAttachShader(ProgramID, FragmentShaderID);
    glLinkProgram(ProgramID);

    // Check the program
    glGetProgramiv(ProgramID, GL_LINK_STATUS, &Result);
    glGetProgramiv(ProgramID, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &InfoLogLength);
    std::vector<char> ProgramErrorMessage( std::max(InfoLogLength, int(1)) );
    glGetProgramInfoLog(ProgramID, InfoLogLength, NULL, &ProgramErrorMessage[0]);
    fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", &ProgramErrorMessage[0]);

    glDeleteShader(VertexShaderID);
    glDeleteShader(FragmentShaderID);

    std::cout.flush();

    return ProgramID;
}
```

Vertex shader:

```
#version 130

in vec4 position;
in vec3 color;

out vec3 f_color;

void main() {
    f_color = color;

    gl_Position = position * gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix;
}
```

Fragment shader:

```
#version 130

in vec3 color;

void main() {
    gl_FragColor = vec4(color, 1);
}
```

For some reason I get just `-1` as the location for both the attributes. Obviously the rest of the errors are caused by invalid location indices?

From OpenGL docs:
`If the named attribute variable is not an active attribute in the specified program object or if name starts with the reserved prefix "gl_", a value of -1 is returned.`

The names do not begin with `gl_` and they are in use in the shaders, so I shouldn't get a value of `-1`. What am I missing?

Comment: Start with the obvious: the first attrib is called 'position' in the shader and you are asking for an attrib called 'location' in the C code.

Comment: You should check the *_STATUS values of the compile/link values as well.

Comment: @FabioCeconello That fixed the first attribute. Do you have any idea about the second (`color`)? 

It is amazing how blind you get to simple mistakes in your own code. I have used four hours looking for that problem and the one in the question is the third "test-case" I have written...

Comment: @BrettHale Is there a case where ShaderInfoLog show nothing, but _RESULT tells about a failure?

Comment: @varesa - OpenGL doesn't mandate anything about the contents of the shader/program logs, AFAIK - so yes, you should check the `Result` value. Even if compilation succeeds, the GL implementation might still provide a log - warnings, helpful hints, the secret of life, etc.

Comment: @BrettHale Ok, I'll fix it. The shader-loader wasn't originally written by me.

Answer (score 3):

You are failing to get an attribute location for `color` because it is not ***active***. While it is true that `color` is used to calculate `f_color` in this example, the fragment shader does not use `f_color` so the linker determines that the vertex attribute named: `color` is inactive.

The solution is quite simple, really:

#### Fragment Shader:

```
#version 130

in vec3 f_color; // RENAMED from color, so that this matches the output from the VS.

void main() {
    gl_FragColor = vec4(f_color, 1);
}
```

It is not an error to re-use the name `color` for different purposes in the Vertex Shader (***input vertex attribute***) and Fragment Shader (***input varying***) stages so the compiler/linker will not complain. It would be an error if you tried to do something like `inout color` though, so this is why you have to pass vertex attributes to geometry/tessellation/fragment shaders using a differently named varying. If the input/output names between stages do not match then chances are quite good that the original vertex attribute will be considered ***inactive***.

---

Also, unless you are transposing your ModelViewProjection matrix, you have the matrix multiplication in your vertex shader backwards. Column-major matrix multiplication, as OpenGL uses, should read right-to-left. That is, you start with an object space position (right-most) and transform to clip space (left-most).

In other words, this is the proper way to transform your vertices...

```
gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * position;

~~~~~~~~~~~   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~   ~~~~~~~~~
 clip space    object space to clip space    obj space
```

Comment: That naming was another one of those getting blind to your own mistakes things... I thought they were the same so I didn't notice