# findAttribLocation returning -1 in WebGL

Tags: javascript, opengl-es, coffeescript, webgl

I know this may happen if the attribute isn't found in my vertex shader, but I'm convinced that it's present. I'll try to provide the most relevant snippets of my large code body:

```
  vertices = new Float32Array(dataArrays.verts)
  normals = new Float32Array(dataArrays.norms)
  uvs = new Float32Array(dataArrays.txtcos)
```

My frag shader:

```
precision highp float;
attribute vec3 aPosition;
attribute vec3 vnorm;
attribute vec2 aTexCoord;
varying vec2 vTexCoord;
uniform mat4 pMatrix;
uniform mat4 vMatrix;
uniform mat4 mMatrix;
void main(void) {
  gl_Position = pMatrix * vMatrix * mMatrix * vec4(aPosition, 1.0);
  vTexCoord = aTexCoord;
}
```

Attribute finder:

```
findAttribLocations = (gl, program, attributes) ->
    out = {}
    i = 0
    while i < attributes.length
      attrib = attributes[i]
      console.log attrib
      out[attrib] = gl.getAttribLocation(program, attrib)
      console.log out[attrib]
      i++
    out
```

Initializer:

```
 TObject::init = (drawingState) ->
    gl = drawingState.gl
    @program = createGLProgram(gl, vertexSource, fragmentSource)
    gl.useProgram @program
    @attributes = findAttribLocations(gl, @program, [
      'aPosition'
      'vnorm'
      'aTexCoord'
    ])
    @uniforms = findUniformLocations(gl, @program, [
      'pMatrix'
      'vMatrix'
      'mMatrix'
      'uTexture'
      'bTexture'
      'lightdir'
    ])
    @texture = createGLTexture(gl, image, true)
    @bumpTexture = createGLTexture(gl, bumpImage, true)
    @buffers[0] = createGLBuffer(gl, vertices, gl.STATIC_DRAW)
    @buffers[1] = createGLBuffer(gl, normals, gl.STATIC_DRAW)
    @buffers[2] = createGLBuffer(gl, uvs, gl.STATIC_DRAW)
    return
```

Program creator:

```
createGLProgram = (gl, vSrc, fSrc) ->
    program = gl.createProgram()
    vShader = createGLShader(gl, gl.VERTEX_SHADER, vSrc)
    fShader = createGLShader(gl, gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER, fSrc)
    gl.attachShader program, vShader
    gl.attachShader program, fShader
    gl.linkProgram program
    if !gl.getProgramParameter(program, gl.LINK_STATUS)
      console.log 'warning: program failed to link'
      return null
    console.log "program"
    console.log program
    program
```

Are there any reasons besides a missing variable in the shader which could be causing this error? I am switching shaders elsewhere in this program, but I believe the correct shaders are being used here. How can I further investigate?

Answer (score 4):

Attributes that are not used by the shader are call *inactive attributes* and do not have bindings.

Since you do not use `vnorm` in the vertex shader, it gets inactive and returns -1 when queried by `glGetAttribLocation`. The only way to get it active is to use it in a shader in a way that it contributes to the output.

See also [the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20098094/cant-get-ids-assigned-to-an-attribute-in-opengl)